# whole phrase priority searching

Tags: mysql, sql

we are implementing a search application

we have implemented a exact word search by the following sql query

```
SELECT *
FROM jreviews_content
WHERE jr_produits REGEXP '[[:<:]]ryan[[:>:]]'
```

which works well now we have another requirement

If the user enter a word "Cabaret Mile-End" various result comes up which has Cabaret and Mile-End in it but the row that has whole phrase in it comes at the lastResult.So i want a whole phrase priority wise searching.

Comment: you could try `SELECT ..... WHERE jr_produits LIKE '%Cabaret Mile-End%'` and `union` this with the previous result to also get the results for the seperate words if you need them

Answer (score 0):

As my comment said:

Try using the `LIKE` structure as follows

```
SELECT * 
FROM jreviews_content
WHERE jr_produits LIKE '%Cabaret Mile-End%'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM jreviews_content
WHERE jr_produits REGEXP '[[:<:]]Cabaret Mile-End[[:>:]]'
```

I dont know what you put in the last query so I put the value just in between.